# Can still sync email after revoking app specific password on gmail

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gmail, sync

I was rather shocked today to discover that my android phone was still syncing email after I had revoked it's app specific password on gmail.

Can anyone else confirm that this happens on their devices too?

Found another users post about it [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/revoke/gmail/JrwhAWWpuoo/_OP-DEXvxNkJ) but there is no reply from google.

Feeling very uneasy about the security of my stuff now :/

**UPDATE:**

Yeah, I was doing it wrong.  But I think Google could document the process a little better.

Comment: Does revoking Android login from here affect it? https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's going on is that your phone is not using your password. When you log in an Oath token is issued. 
This is more secure, because your password is not stored on the device. It also has the additional benefit that it can automatically log you in in your browser. To deny access to your phone, remove the authentication token [here](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens).

Moreover starting with ICS you don't need to use applications specific passwords for your phone. Enter your regular Google account info; it will notice that you have 2-factor authentication enabled and open an internal browser where you can log in using your OTP.

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you.  But now I'm a little confused -  So are you saying that even on Gingerbread this was the way to revoke access? If so, what was the 'revoke app specific password' button for?

Did Google publicise this change between ICS and prior versions? I hadn't read anything (obviously ;)

Comment: I'm not sure about GB as I only tried this on ICS and I don't have another device at hand. If it was publicized, it didn't reach me (nor the 10+ Android blogs that I'm reading) I only found out about this by accident. As for the revoke password: The app engine SDK, the music manager Google Talk client, email clients and many other stuff still needs a password so it still has a use case.

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll update that google forum thread with this info too (I wasn't the only one confused!)